# Kafka - views behave like a form of continuously updated cache ? How

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

"views behave like a form of continuously updated cache" ?

Is this mean stream consumer application which listen to Kafka keep on updating the view or cache and cached data is stored on client machine instead of kafka server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Kafka` by itself does not have the notion of "view".

`Kafka Streams` allows you to build a `KTable` or a `GlobalKTable` which can act as a a view or a cache.

> Is this mean stream consumer application which listen to Kafka keep on updating the view or cache

Yes, it is the consumer application which is in charge of maintaining the cache or view, based on the events the application consumed from the Kafka topic. (And a Kafka Stream Application can be seen as a consumer application.)

> and cached data is stored on client machine instead of kafka server?

The consumer application needs to store the current state somewhere, true.

But the data will also remain in the Kafka topic.

Comment: Thanks Val Bonn. But the data will also remain in the Kafka topic. - raw data will be available on Kafka. Processed data will remain on client side. But at client side will it used memory or disk to store it. If it uses disk then it is going to impact the available disk space on that client machine.??

Comment: `But at client side will it used memory or disk to store it` -> It's up the client app to decide if it wants to store it in memory or on disk. I think that in most of the cases, it would be stored on disk: in this case, when the app is restarted, it does not need to consume the complete topic again to build the cache. `If it uses disk then it is going to impact the available disk space on that client machine.?` --> Yes, if you save something on disk, it consumes space... Maybe did I misunderstood your question?